# Compare datetime column in different databases with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, compare, synchronize

**THE SCENARIO:**

I have 2 different servers (SERVER_A and SERVER_B) running **SQL Server Express** on each one, with same table definition on both databases.

The table definition is:

```
KEY integer
VALUE nvarchar(30)
LAST_UPDATE datetime
```

Each time the user updates the VALUE, a trigger puts `GETDATE()` into `LAST_UPDATE`.

**NEED:**

I need to get the last edited "VALUE" for a given "KEY", from SERVER_A or SERVER_B.

To achieve this, I linked "SERVER_B" with "SERVER_A" and I ran:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN TA.LAST_UPDATE >= TB.LAST_UPDATE THEN TA.VALUE
      ELSE TB.VALUE
   END AS NEWERVALUE
FROM SERVER_A.DATABASEA.dbo.TABLEA TA 
   INNER JOIN SERVER_B.DATABASEB.dbo.TABLEB TB ON TA.KEY = TB.KEY
WHERE TA.KEY = 1234
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

Can occur that the user edits a row in SERVER_A for a certain KEY and a few seconds or minutes later, edit in SERVER_B for the same KEY. The difference in system datetime of servers machines, makes the query returns the SERVER_A VALUE incorrectly.

**Example:**

```
SERVER_A  has the time:  2016-01-01 14:03:30
SERVER_B  has the time:  2016-01-01 14:00:00
```

User updates and set the `VALUE="one"` for `KEY=1234` in SERVER_A. The column `LAST_UPDATE` will be `2016-01-01 14:03:30`.
One minute later, the user updates and set the `VALUE="two"` for `KEY=1234` in SERVER_B. The column `LAST_UPDATE` will be `2016-01-01 14:01:00`.

If I run my query, get the VALUE "one" as newest. This is erroneous.

Comment: I assume you can't sync the servers system time via NTP or any other method to make them the same?

Comment: Aside from the above, I'd look into creating a trigger to a log table on both servers. When server a is updated a trigger is fired and a row is added to server b log table with its system time and visa versa. This would be bilateral of course. Not elegant but somewhat feasible.

Comment: Thanks scximon. I thought on NTP, but the machines are not in domain. I want to run "net time \\SERVER_A /set /yes" periodically, but the machines have installed Deep Freeze and block time change. Do you suggest an alternative?

Comment: What about the trigger idea above?

Comment: I should say that the two servers are not connected all the time. One of them is running on a mobile device that has no connection to the Internet on the working day. At the end of the day, both servers are connected to synchronize data. I'm thinking of a solution without triggers nor log tables. Ideas?